# Linking tables together between two models in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to get this result: [Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzxYR.jpg) (get a link to go to the other associate table)

I'm following the official tutorial of cakephp to linking tables together but
but it's not working.

My database is like this:

**Table ciudades:**

| id (int 4) PK | nombreCiudad (varchar 60)|

**Table complejos:**

| idComplejo (int 11) PK | nombre (varchar 25)| ciudad_id (int 4) FK |

The complete ciudad column in my complejo table is empty when I want to show the name of the another asociation model (ciudad nombreCiudad). I want to show the name, not the Id of Ciudad.
Here you can see the empty column:[Click Me 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xLPm.jpg)

When I want to show the result, in index.ctp **"$complejo->has('ciudad')"** returns false:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('idComplejo') ?></th>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('nombre') ?></th>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('ciudad_id') ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($complejos as $complejo): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($complejo->idComplejo) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($complejo->nombre) ?></td>
            <td><?= $complejo->has('ciudad') ? $this->Html->link($complejo->ciudad->nombreCiudad, ['controller' => 'Ciudades', 'action' => 'view', $complejo->ciudad->id]) : '' ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $complejo->idComplejo]) ?>
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $complejo->idComplejo]) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $complejo->idComplejo], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $complejo->idComplejo)]) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here you can see the relationship between ciudades and complejos
**ComplejosTable.php**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('complejos');
    $this->displayField('idComplejo');
    $this->displayField('nombre');


    $this->belongsTo('Ciudades', [
        'foreignKey' => 'ciudad_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}

 public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['ciudad_id'], 'Ciudades'));
    return $rules;
}
```

And here is **CiudadesTable.php**

```
...


public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('ciudades');
    $this->displayField('nombreCiudad');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('Complejos', [
        'foreignKey' => 'ciudad_id'
    ]);



}
```

Finally, in my **ComplejosController** I have:

```
public function index()
{

    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Ciudades']
    ];
    $this->set('complejos', $this->paginate());
    $this->set('_serialize', ['complejos']);
}
```

What can I do to resolve my problem?  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp empty Associations on Linking Tables Together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625943/cakephp-empty-associations-on-linking-tables-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change **ciudad** for **ciudade**

```
<td><?= $complejo->has('ciudade') ? $this->Html->link($complejo->ciudade->nombreCiudad, ['controller' => 'Ciudades', 'action' => 'view', $complejo->ciudade->id]) : '' ?></td>
```

For Cakephp singular of **Ciudades** is **Ciudade** not *Ciudad*

Answer (score 0):

Your:

```
<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('user_id') ?></th>
```

Seems to be referencing user_id which is not available in your  **CiudadesTable**. You might want to change it to

```
  <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('ciudad_id') ?></th>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, sorry i have a mistake with this part of code, I corrected it, but still not working